# jQuery object-- what happens in the code below?

Tags: jquery

Could anyone explain to me what's likely happening in this snippet of jQuery below?

```
        var tileDiv = $('<div/>', { 'class': 'tile', 'text': this.name, 'id': this.tileId });
        tileDiv.css('border-top', '5px solid ' + this.scenes[sceneId].borderColor);
        tileDiv.data(this);
```

To me, it looks like `tileDiv` is set to a jQuery object with two values in it-- `<div/>` and the second bit after the comma.  Not 100% sure what's happening with the `tileDiv.data(this)` call however.  Thanks for the clarifications or best guesses.

Comment: Well, would be good to see to what ´this´ is pointing.

Comment: My guess is it probably needs to be `tileDiv.data(this.name, this)`

Comment: Thanks for your replies, I should have included more code.  'this' refers to an element in a javascript array, iterated over just above the code you see, using this line: `$(tiles).each(function(index) {...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code is creating a new `div` with the properties passed in the second argument, and storing the jQuery object in `tileDiv`:

```
var tileDiv = $('<div/>', { 'class': 'tile', 'text': this.name, 'id': this.tileId });
```

And then adding the `border-top` CSS property:

```
tileDiv.css('border-top', '5px solid ' + this.scenes[sceneId].borderColor);
```

As for the last line, the `.data` function allows you to store and retrieve data associated with that jQuery object. It can also be used to retrieve information from HTML5 `data-` attributes on the element. In this case, all members of `this` will be stored in `tileDiv`'s data. If you had:

```
this.someData = 99;
this.otherData = 87;
tileDiv.data(this);
```

Then `tileDiv.data('someData')` will return 99 and `tileDiv.data('otherData')` will return 87, as you can see in [this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TfYWD/).

See the documentation for jQuery `.data` here: [`.data` jQuery API](http://api.jquery.com/data/).

Answer (score 1):

Data is a JQuery command that stores metadata in a DOM object:  http://api.jquery.com/data/  The data can be anything you like.  You add data like this:

```
tileDiv.data(key, object_with_data)
```

and retrieve it like this:

```
var tileDiv.data(key);
```

So yeah, it looks like the above retrieves the data but doesn't do anything with it.

Answer (score 1):

`data` is a HTML 5 prefix for HTML attributes. If we know that `this` in your context is a basic string like "hello" jQuery tryies to get a attribute HTML attribute named `data-hello`.
But as you can see your object don't have any attribute like that so nothing is happening.

Its equal to write

```
 $(titleDiv).attr("data-" + this)
```

Answer (score 1):

The first line creates a new div, sets the `id` and `class` attributes, then sets the inner text of the div.

The second line sets the top border style.

The third line attaches data to the new div that equals all the properties of the `this` object, which I am guessing is a Javascript object created through a `new Something` constructor although it could also be a plain Object.

So if `this.answer = 42`, the result of `tileDiv.data("answer")` would also be 42 after the third line executed.

Seems a bit wasteful to copy all the properties of `this`, it might have been better to say `tileDiv.data("tileInfo", this)` instead but it's hard to tell without seeing more code.